# Add dynamic key to set state, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

I have this state

```
this.state = {
   dropdown1: false,
   dropdown2: false,
   dropdown3: false
}
```

I want to access to these dropdowns in state using this.setState but the number after 'dropdown' comes from API

```
onMaca = (ev) => {
   this.setState({
       dropdown + ev: true
    })
}
```

So I want the key to be dynamic 'dropdown1' for example.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

you can access the object property like this **object['property name']**

```js
onMaca = (ev) => {
this.state['dropdown' + ev]= true;
   this.setState({
       ...this.state
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codezup.com/add-dynamic-key-to-object-property-in-javascript/

You can use any of these to set key dynamically. I will try to update the answer with an example in a while for setState.

Answer (score 0):

The state is a JS object, so you can get its keys as usual, like so:

```
const stateKeys = this.state.keys()
```

Now you have an array:  `[ "dropdown1", "dropdown1", "dropdown1" ]`
One way to use it would be:

```
const keysMap = statekeys.map(( item, i ) => return { 
  key: item,  
  idx: i,  
  number: item.replace( /dropdown/, '' )  
}
```

keysMap will look like so: `[ { key: 'dropdown1', idx: 0, number "1" }, { key: 'dropdown1', idx: 1, number "2" }, { key: 'dropdown1', idx: 2, number "3" } ]`
You can query `keysMap` for a given `dropDownNumber` like so:

```
let k = keysMap.find( kmap => kmap.key = dropDownNumber )
```

To set the dropdown's state:

```
this.setState({ k: <whatever> })
```